# What is the common way to detect a client/server version mismatch

Tags: c#, client-server, protocol-buffers, grpc

We are implementing a client/server application to run our hardware on remote system.

To do that we use GRPC, protobuf v3.

When we modify the `.proto` files and recompile the client without updating the server, we got an exception with an obscure message:

> Exception was thrown by handler.

Using GRPC, what is the common way to detect a client/server version mismatch ?

**Edit: An example of modification**

For example we change this (specific type for message parameter) :

```cs
service RpcAcquisitionCard {
    ...
    rpc SetNumericalControlOscillator(RpcNcoConfiguration)
    ...
}

message RpcNco {
    RpcDeviceIdentifier deviceId = 1;
    core.protobuf.RpcFrequency nco1 = 2;
    core.protobuf.RpcFrequency nco2 = 3;
}
```

To this (generic type for message parameter)

```
service RpcAcquisitionCard {
    ...
    rpc SetNumericalControlOscillator(RpcCommandParameter)
    ...
}

message RpcCommandParameter {
    RpcDeviceIdentifier deviceId = 1;
    google.protobuf.Any parameter = 2;
}

message RpcNco {
    core.protobuf.RpcFrequency nco1 = 1;
    core.protobuf.RpcFrequency nco2 = 2;
}
```

Where the `RpcCommandParameter.parameter` field is a `RpcNco`.

Comment: protobuf is backwards **and** forwards compatible. How are you altering the proto such that they are no longer compatible?

Comment: I added an example of modification.

Comment: Protobuf v3. We are in the early phase of the development.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When using protobuf it is recommended to read the [Language Guide](https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers/docs/proto3).

https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers/docs/proto3#updating is particularly relevant to your scenario:

> Fields can be removed, as long as the tag number is not used again in
>   your updated message type. You may want to rename the field instead,
>   perhaps adding the prefix "OBSOLETE_", or make the tag reserved, so
>   that future users of your .proto can't accidentally reuse the number.

That is the bit you are doing incorrectly. Rather than changing:

```
message RpcNco {
    RpcDeviceIdentifier deviceId = 1;
    core.protobuf.RpcFrequency nco1 = 2;
    core.protobuf.RpcFrequency nco2 = 3;
}
```

to:

```
message RpcNco {
    core.protobuf.RpcFrequency nco1 = 1;
    core.protobuf.RpcFrequency nco2 = 2;
}
```

you should change it to:

```
message RpcNco {
    RpcDeviceIdentifier OBSOLETE_deviceId = 1;
    core.protobuf.RpcFrequency nco1 = 2;
    core.protobuf.RpcFrequency nco2 = 3;
}
```

*Then your client and server will be able to communicate with each other, regardless of whether they have the old protobuf definition or the new one.*

Comment: Thanks for your response, we are in the early phase of the development and the .proto files move a lot. We don't want to mark obsolete message that will never be in production. My question is more about detecting mismatch with an explicit message than avoid them.

Comment: I suppose I am challenging the direction you are taking. Protobuf has an inbuilt mechanism for solving this problem. The pain you are in now is **specifically** because you aren't following the standard. _If you went to a doctor and said you were in pain since you kept hitting your head on a wall, the doctor isn't going to tell you how to hit the wall in a gentler way or give you painkillers. He/she is going to suggest you stop hitting your head on the wall._

Comment: Actually we are starting to learn how to walk with GRPC, and yes we hit the wall multiple times. Ok GRPC is cool on a long run to manage versioning issue (if we follow the guide lines, which gives the API user a lot of responsibility). But I'm still surprised by the message provided in case of client/server mismatch, it's helpless. I would expect a clear exception message with information about the sent message and something about the server doesn't managing it. Anyway, my college has been stuck on this 3 days because he didn't update the server side correctly. He learns this the hard way.